# default log4net configuration

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, log4net

I have the following code:

```
    public Log4NetLogger()
        : base(LogLevel.Debug)
    {
        if(!LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
        {
            lock(mLocker)
            {
                if(!LogManager.GetRepository().Configured)
                {
                    XmlConfigurator.Configure();
                }
            }
        }

        mLog4NetInstance = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log4NetLogger));
    }
```

With the following web.config:

```xml
  <log4net>
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <file value="Logs\MaMLog_" />
      <appendToFile value="true" />
      <StaticLogFileAppName value="false" />
      <rollingStyle value="Date" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMMdd_dddd'.log'" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date{dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss,fff} [%thread] -() %message%newline" />
      </layout>
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
    </appender>
    <logger name="MyLog1">
      <level value="Debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
    <logger name="MyLog2">
      <level value="Debug" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
    </logger>
  </log4net>
```

How does the code know the logger name? If at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using

```
mLog4NetInstance = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(Log4NetLogger));
```

then the logger name will be the value of `typeof(Log4NetLogger).FullName` which is usually of the form `YourNameSpace.Log4NetLogger`

Nothing will be logged in this example, because you don't have a logger with that name and you don't have a root section to fall back to , eg

```
<root>
    <level value="DEBUG" />
    <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
</root>
```

Comment: `YourNameSpace.Log4NetLogger` --> then I have to define a logger to each assembly in my sln if I don;t want to use `<root>` or will the assmebly of the start project is enough?

Comment: If you are using GetLogger(typeof(xxx)), then you can use the first part of your namespace (which doesn't have to be related to the assembly name). If your namespace is MyCompany.MyProduct, then log4net will look for a logger for MyCompany.MyProduct.Log4NetLogger and if doesn't find that, it will look for a logger for MyCompany.MyProduct and then MyCompany and finally the root logger.